# redux-observable epic chain dispatches duplicate actions

Tags: angular, redux, redux-observable

## Legend

`action-chain epic` = Epic, which returns 'success' or 'fail' action, based on service call.
`service` = Http service, from `HttpModule`, Angular2

## The goal

I need to send data to server. I have a `CREATE`, `CREATE_SUCCESS` and `CREATE_FAIL` actions. My idea is to dispatch `CREATE` on submit. Then I have an `action-chain epic`, which starts `service` call to my server and fires `CREATE_SUCCESS` or `CREATE_FAIL` depending on the response.

## The problem

My `action-chain epic` fires duplicate actions - in both cases it fires two actions, eg: in case of success, for every `CREATE` it dispatches two `CREATE_SUCCESS` actions.

## The code

```
 private createAnimalActionChain() {
        return action$ => {
            return action$
                .ofType(AnimalActions.CREATE)
                .switchMap(action => {
                    return this.service
                        .create(action.payload)
                        .map(httpResponse => {
                            let response = httpResponse.json()
                            if (response.success) {
                                return this.actions.createSuccess()
                            }

                            return this.actions.createFail(response.errors)
                        })
                })
        }
    }
```

This is what I composed and it's working for the most part. If there is a better approach, I am all ears. Dispatching multiple actions was not real problem until recently, but it never seemed ok with me, so I'd love to fix it.

**EDIT**: I have just found out that sometimes my app dispatches duplicate actions before any Epic is executed. I am now trying to understand why.

**EDIT 2**: Nevermind **EDIT**. It was an isolated case, where submit event was bubbling all the way to the top, and because I named my `@Output()` field 'submit' - it caused double action dispatch. It is fixed now and is not relevant to the Epic issue, described above. It still persists.

**EDIT 3**: With the help of @jayphelps, I was able to track the issue. It turns out my actions, called from the epic chain, triggered twice. I am not sure why that happens though. Here is my old code:

```
static CREATE = 'CREATE'
static CREATE_SUCCESS = 'CREATE_SUCCESS'
static CREATE_FAIL = 'CREATE_FAIL'
@dispatch()
create = (animal: IAnimal) => ({
    type: AnimalActions.CREATE,
    payload: animal
})
@dispatch()
createSuccess = () => ({
    type: AnimalActions.CREATE_SUCCESS
})
@dispatch()
createFail = (errors: object) => ({
    type: AnimalActions.CREATE_FAIL,
    payload: errors
})
```

This code dispatches `CREATE` once, `CREATE_SUCCESS` twice and `CREATE_FAIL` twice. I removed the last two `@dispatch()` decorators:

```
static CREATE = 'CREATE'
static CREATE_SUCCESS = 'CREATE_SUCCESS'
static CREATE_FAIL = 'CREATE_FAIL'
@dispatch()
create = (animal: IAnimal) => ({
    type: AnimalActions.CREATE,
    payload: animal
})
createSuccess = () => ({
    type: AnimalActions.CREATE_SUCCESS
})
createFail = (errors: object) => ({
    type: AnimalActions.CREATE_FAIL,
    payload: errors
})
```

This code seems to work properly and only fire one of each action. I am very confused as to why this works like that. According to [API docs](https://angular-redux.github.io/store/globals.html#dispatch) this property decorates a single action-creator function and dispatches its return value, an action object. it is very weird, because I call `CREATE` and `CREATE_SUCCESS` identically. How does this decorator work?

**EDIT 4**:
I have narrowed the behavior down to this: If I call an action from within my Epic and this action is decorated with `@dispatch`, it is triggered twice. I suspect that the Epic, being a middleware internally dispatches the received action. The problem comes, if I need to manually dispatch an action from my container component.

## The solution

With the help of jayphelps. Thanks for your response. However I like the `@dispatch` decoration, for use inside of my components. A presonal solution I found is structuring my action chain in a manner that `starter-actions` (those that dispatch from inside a component) do not get dispatched via Epic. Then just decorate those `starter-actions` with `@dispatch` and it works.

Comment: did you mean that for every CREATE the action fires twice ?

Comment: @eenagy Yes, that's what I meant. Editing for more clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code provided is fine; see here, only one `CREATE_SUCCESS`: https://jsbin.com/tagovok/edit?js,output

This suggests the problem is in code not provided here. Three immediate possibilities I can think of:

- Somewhere, somehow you're dispatching two `CREATE` actions (use redux devtools to see)
- `this.service.create(action.payload)` actually emits **two** things instead of one (use `do`, `debugger`s, or you could even just add a `.take(1)` after it and if that fixes it you know)
- You have the same epic added twice, e.g. `combineEpics(yourEpic, yourEpic)` (this one is hard to confirm. Maybe try adding a counter to the initial call of the epic it and confirming it only gets incremented to 1 since the epic function itself is only ever called once)

---

### Update based on yours:

> I have narrowed the behavior down to this: If I call an action from within my Epic and this action is decorated with @dispatch(), it is triggered twice. I suspect that the Epic, being a middleware internally dispatches the received action. The problem comes, if I need to manually dispatch an action from my container component.

Indeed redux-observable will automatically dispatch actions emitted by your Epics. I don't have experience using angular-redux, but there is some docs on using it with redux-observable here: https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/epics.md

A quick skim suggests they do not use the action creators in the epics and instead just use POJO. You could still create action creators that only return the POJO actions, [just normal redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators).

Comment: @alex you can try with the provided help, and if it's still doesn't solve your problem, than I suggest that you update your answer with the missing details

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ran through those thoughts and the only potential issue I found is using the `@dispatch()` decorator from `angular-redux/store`. I must be dispatching the duplicates. I have not registered excess epics, I dispatch single `CREATE` action (confirmed via Redux dev tools). I will try to dispatch in a regular way.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. My **epic** dispatches the _same action_ twice. While In my case that happens only in my _tests_ for the **epic**. Debugging my app using `redux-dev-tools` show only one action dispatched. FYI, I am consuming the redux store in a **React** app.

Comment: @jayphelps Can you help me with my issue? Why am I getting two duplicate actions? Shall I create a separate question for this issue?

Comment: @besrabasant do you have a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: @jayphelps No, but I have solved the issue. It seems that there was a GitHub issue for this which I was unable to find. And I got the solution from your comment on that issue. https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/389#issuecomment-354623405